# Why does GetWindowPlacement always return the MaxPosition -1, -1?

Tags: c#

Why does [GetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518.aspx) always return (-1, -1) for MaxPosition? I have not been able to get any other result so far.

```
var f = new Form();
f.Show();
// Position in second monitor
f.Bounds = new Rectangle(2100, 10, 200, 200);
f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

var wp = new User32.WINDOWPLACEMENT { Length = Marshal.SizeOf<User32.WINDOWPLACEMENT>() };
if (!User32.GetWindowPlacement(f.Handle, ref wp)) throw new Win32Exception();

// wp.ptMaxPosition.X == -1 and wp.ptMaxPosition.Y == -1
```

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632611.aspx), `ptMaxPosition` contains 'The coordinates of the window's upper-left corner when the window is maximized.'

Comment: GetWindowPlacement() is an odd-duck function.  It returns values in "workspace coordinates" for non-tool windows.  The MSDN article specifically warns that the values it returns are only usable in SetWindowPlacement() calls.  It is very unclear to me what problem you are trying to solve, good odds however that you are looking for WM_GETMINMAXINFO.

Comment: I'd rather not have to hook the windows. The aim is a one-off save/restore for layouts of the windows belonging to an app.

Answer (score -1):

Because it is set 1 pixel outside of the screen when maximized, to hide part of the frame. Remember that window size is not the client area size but includes things like the frames and the top bar.

1 pixel of that is hidden when maximized.

Comment: No, if I drag it to a different window and maximize it, the MaxPosition coordinates are the same. Also, the actual bounds end up -8, -8.

Comment: IOf you drag it it changes the coordinates, but not the coordinates it would have when maximized because it then IS NOT MAXIMIZED.

Comment: If you drag it and maximize it in a second or third screen, then yes.